# Pass in callback url when seeking request

Tags: c#, api, twitter

I'm adding twitter integration to my companies web application but I'm hitting a snag on it.

The issue currently is with the callback url.

In twitter it seems that it wants to have a set value but the way our application is setup, each customer that access the site has their own url.

ideally I'd like to set the callback url on the fly, but I'm having a hard time finding any information on that.

EDIT:
Think I may need to add some more details here to better help you help me

The issue is I setup the callback url parameter to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token but when I go to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize to get permission, it will go to the callback setup on the api, not what I set from the previous request.

here is what my code looks like:

```
    public string oAuthToken(string callbackUrl)
    {
        Uri oauthUrl = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
        var oauthNonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
        var oauthTimestamp = this.GenerateTimeStamp();
        var oauthSignature = "";

        var authSignature = string.Format("oauth_callback=\"{0}\"&oauth_consumer_key=\"{1}\"&oauth_nonce=\"{2}\"&oauth_signature_method=\"{3}\"&oauth_timestamp=\"{4}\"&oauth_version=\"{5}\"",
            Uri.EscapeDataString(callbackUrl),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(this.ConsumerKey),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthNonce),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthSignatureMethod),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthTimestamp),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthVersion));

        var baseString = string.Format("POST&{0}&{1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthUrl.AbsoluteUri), Uri.EscapeDataString(authSignature));
        var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(this.ConsumerSecret), "&");

        using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
        {
            oauthSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
        }

        var authHeader = string.Format("oauth oauth_callback=\"{0}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{1}\", oauth_nonce=\"{2}\", oauth_signature=\"{3}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{4}\", oauth_timestamp=\"{5}\", oauth_version=\"{6}\"",
            Uri.EscapeDataString(callbackUrl),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(this.ConsumerKey),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthNonce),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthSignature),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthSignatureMethod),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthTimestamp),
            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauthVersion));

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        HttpWebRequest authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(oauthUrl);

        authRequest.Method = "POST";
        authRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        authRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        authRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        authRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

        try
        {
            using (var response = authRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).", response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription));
                }

                var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

I always get a 401 error back.

Comment: I have decided to use TweetSharp for now, though I'd like to find a better solution as this library is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in the application set-up at https://apps.twitter.com/ a callback URL is required, the OAuth 1.0A spec mandates that a callback URL be passed with the request token. You can pass any valid URL to with that request, effectively having each of your callbacks go to the unique URL for each of your users. So, you're not locked into the callback URL in your application's set-up.

Comment: ah ok, the thing that keeps alluding me is how do I set the other callback url. seems like everything time i use oauth_callback its still using the default callback setup by the api.

Comment: You'll need to pass the `callback_url` param with the percent-encoded callback URL to the the [request_token endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/request_token). You can see a [working example](http://quiet-retreat-1002.herokuapp.com/) of this in a demo app, though it's written in Python.

Comment: a code sample would be helpful, otherwise I don't see how we can help you

Comment: I'll have to try to scrap something up, its all scattered around.